# Generating an Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

So I want to have some kind of number geenrator for the following idea that I have and it goes:

**Problem:** For each event $A,$ a single worker $X$ gains some distinct number of points. The points will then be added up as more events are taken. Now when a worker reaches a milestones he is able to exchange the points for a prize (e.g. car ).

The challenge is then to calculate how many points are needed for each prize, but also how many points are gained for each event by the worker. The prize values must be correlated to the amount of profit/revenue per event done so the company will not lose any money.

I clearly have all the ideas in my head but I just can not seem to find a systematic way of assigning all these values. Can anyone try to help me please?

Comment: Mathematics only comes in if you gives us some hints about your "ideas".

Comment: This is the idea but I have little clue on how to generate an algorithm. Or no clue on how to put this in numbers or 'maths'.